# error LNK2005 with generated symbol names

Tags: visual-c++

1>expression.obj : error LNK2005: "??@10f67d10f2509d1b7ae3d4b0285ba9c5@" (??@10f67d10f2509d1b7ae3d4b0285ba9c5@) already defined in determineSwitchBranches.obj
1>expression.obj : error LNK2005: "??@7d18b7ced3468f6b7bb84d399883984b@" (??@7d18b7ced3468f6b7bb84d399883984b@) already defined in determineSwitchBranches.obj
1>expression.obj : error LNK2005: "??@84d623799b2629b9bf1736313b3256f5@" (??@84d623799b2629b9bf1736313b3256f5@) already defined in determineSwitchBranches.obj
1>expression.obj : error LNK2005: "??@cabc6fa94b805937911b53b075b3724c@" (??@cabc6fa94b805937911b53b075b3724c@) already defined in determineSwitchBranches.obj
1>expression.obj : error LNK2005: "??@d227a1556c429ce3c346b6ffae37f517@" (??@d227a1556c429ce3c346b6ffae37f517@) already defined in determineSwitchBranches.obj
1>C:\Users\pfoelsch\Documents\SYMPHONY\symphony\src\veriloga\modelcompiler\src\x64\Debug\smc.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "smc.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

When I combine the two offending .cpp files into a single one, the linker complains about two other .obj files....

the project builds fine using g++ 5.5 and 7.3

Comment: Work on a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. You have something defined more than once, perhaps in a header that multiple files include, but without an example it's just a guess. You should also look at your precompiled headers settings. If you have it turned on but have used it incorrectly, which is quite easy to do, it can cause issues like this.

Comment: @Retired Ninja -- such an example would already be the answer wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by also creating .asm files with source code annotation and then looking what line in the source corresponds to the offending symbol names (project_properties/C++/output_files/assembler_output=assembly_with_source_code).
There was some templated class with a virtual method in some .h file:

```
template<typename>
class A
{
    virtual void b(void) const;
};
template<typename>
void A::b(void)
{
}
```

and one .cpp file!!! contained a specialization of b:

```
template<>
void A<something>::b(void)
{
}
```

Adding some header for this into the .h file solved the problem! (Again: The offending source built fine with various g++ versions):

```
template<>
void A<something>::b(void);
```